# Javascript Transform recursively object that refer to other attribute using lodash or other lib

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to transform javascript object that refer each other by its attribute,

Says I have this object

```
{
  apple: {
    banana: [1,2,3],
    cherry: [4,5,6],
  },
  banana: {
    date: [7],
    cherry: [8,9],
    elderberry: [10, 11],
  },
  cherry: {
   date: [7],
   fig:  [12,13],
  },
  date: {
    fig: [11,14],
  },
},
```

And I want to transform that object into this

```
{
  apple: {
    banana: [1,2,3],
    cherry: [4,5,6, 8,9],
    date: [7],
    elderberry: [10, 11],
    fig: [11,14, 12,13],
  },
  banana: {
    cherry: [8,9],
    elderberry: [10, 11],
    fig: [11,14, 12,13],
    date: [7],
  },
  cherry: {
    date: [7],
    fig: [11,14, 12,13],
  },
  date: {
    fig: [11,14],
  },
}
```

At that example attribute cherry at apple, has [4,5,6, 8,9], 
[4,5,6] is coming from apple and [8, 9] is coming from banana, because apple has reference to banana and banana has reference cherry, therefore it will be merged into [4,5,6, 8,9]

and also the final array is actually unique value

So the idea is it will recursively merge other component value, using lodash or other library is okay ~

Comment: You say recursively, but it looks your example only looks up to a certain depth. For instance: from `a`, to `b`, to `d`, we get to `f: [11, 14]`. So why is that not in the `f` list of `a`?

Comment: sorry will update the example

Comment: What happens when there are duplicate values in the final arrays? Could you cover that also in your example?

Comment: actually the final array is always unique, already update the example too, thanks :)

Comment: Examples that use single letters for property names make it much more difficult to talk about the problem ("The c that's a property of a or the c that's a property of b"). Much better to use unique words.

Comment: @HereticMonkey updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a structure that stores the opposite relationships, i.e. from child to parent.

Then for each key/array pair, follow the path (via the new structure) upward to its ancestors and for each of them add the array to the same key there. I have chosen a traversal using an explicit stack variable for this, but it would work just as well with a recursive DFS traversal.

Finally visit all arrays again to remove the duplicates.

```js
function complete(data) {
    // Create child-parent relationships:
    const parents = {};
    for (const parent in data) {
        for (const child in data[parent]) {
            (parents[child] = parents[child] || []).push(parent);
        }
    }
    // Tree traveral to copy child array into same key in ancestors
    const result = {};
    for (const parent in data) {
        for (const child in data[parent]) {
            const arr = data[parent][child];
            const visited = new Set;
            const stack = [parent];
            while (stack.length) {
                const node = stack.pop();
                if (visited.has(node)) continue;
                visited.add(node);
                ((result[node] = result[node] || {})[child] = result[node][child] || []).push(...arr);
                stack.push(...parents[node] || []);
            }
        }
    }
    // Remove duplicate values from the arrays
    for (const parent in result) {
        for (const child in result[parent]) {
            result[parent][child] = [...new Set(result[parent][child])];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Example call with data from the question:
const data = {apple: {banana: [1,2,3],cherry: [4,5,6],},banana: {date: [7],cherry: [8,9],elderberry: [10, 11],},cherry: {date: [7],fig:  [12,13],},date: {fig: [11,14],},};
const result = complete(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a nested approach with a recursive function with an exit marker.

```js
const
    iter = (object, key, target, sub) => Object
        .keys(object[key] || {})
        .reduce((o, k) => {
            o[k] = Array.from(new Set([...(o[k] || []), ...object[key][k]]));
            return sub
                ? iter(object, k, o)
                : o;
        }, target);

var object = { apple: { banana: [1, 2, 3], cherry: [4, 5, 6], }, banana: { date: [7], cherry: [8, 9], elderberry: [10, 11], }, cherry: { date: [7], fig: [12, 13], }, date: { fig: [11, 14] } },
    result = Object.keys(object).reduce((o, k) => {
        iter(object, k, o[k] = o[k] || {}, true);
        return o;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive approach for each sub-key (the `addKeys` function), by using `Object.entries()` with `Array.reduce()`, and passing the current existing keys whenever you call the function again to avoid an eternal loop.

Then you can reduce the entries of the `data` object, and call `addKeys` for each key.

```js
const data = {"apple":{"banana":[1,2,3],"cherry":[4,5,6]},"banana":{"date":[7],"cherry":[8,9],"elderberry":[10,11]},"cherry":{"date":[7],"fig":[12,13]},"date":{"fig":[11,14]}}

const addKeys = (obj = {}, existing = []) => 
  Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((r, [k, v]) =>
      existing.includes(k) ? r : 
      ({
        ...r,
        [k]: v,
        ...addKeys(data[k], [...existing, k, ...Object.keys(r)]),
      })
    , {})

// iterate the data object and rebuild it by adding keys to each sub-key
const result = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    r[k] = addKeys(v);
    
    return r;
  }, {})
  
console.log(result)
```